# Is the token provided upon login platform or device dependent?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, device, token

I'm testing the login with FB feature for IOS (using version 5) and I encountered what could be a possible problem for me.

When I try on the simulator, the token returned is different than the one returned when I login on my real device. IS it supposed to be this way ? IS this a bug ?

If the token is related to the platform type(iOS simulator, real iPhone, iPad) , it could be a major problem for me since to identify my user I could only rely on the id :/.

For now I was checkin the couple ID/token.

If the token is platform dependent, would it at least be the same on each model of the platform type ? I mean If i login once from a iPhone 3G, then from an iPhone4, etc... would i get the same token ?

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.
I'm writing a facebook module for an app.
While testing on the simulator, 
everything worked fine.
But after the test with the same source code on the device,
I had an OAuthException 2500.
On the device I have an facebook client, 
but not on the simulator.
At the first run with the simulator I had to log in with my my email and password, 
and so I got the access key.
On the device I already have an access key through the facebook client.
Maybe that's the point?
Please answer if someone knows the issue.
Meanwhile I have to dig to the problem...